Charset utf8 appended with application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type in spring boot rest template
I am calling a third party Post API through Rest template and content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and spring boot appends charset utf8 by default which is causing API call failure. Can I remove charset utf8 somehow ?

You should check what is third party API accepts. Try to find a working example. What about using HttpMessageConverter ?

Third party does not accept utf8 charset. How can I use HttpMessageConverter?

You should update your post and share your code snipped, but the idea is about enforcing another encoding other than UTF-8.

Do not want to apply any encoding.  Let me update

Then share your code please.

I have done it by overriding write method of FormHttpMessageConverter where I removed charset parameter

You need to set the content-type="application/json" Http header explicitly for that POST call request you are making.
